# How to pass a parameter to a batch file containing a % without it 'breaking'?

Tags: batch-file

**The Problem**

In a main batch file, values are pulled from a .txt file (and `SET` as values of variables within this batch file). These values may each contain `%` characters.

These are read from the .txt file with no issues. However, when a variable with a value containing a `%` character is passed to a second batch file, the second batch file interprets any `%` characters as a variable expansion. *(Note: There is **no** control over the second batch file.)*

**Example**

```
echo %PERCENTVARIABLE%
```

Output: `I%LOVE%PERCENT%CHARACTERS%`

When passed to a second file and then echo'ed, would *(probably)* become `IPERCENT`, as it interprets `%LOVE%` and `%CHARACTERS%` as unset variables.

---

**Research**

I found the syntax to find and replace elements within a string in a batch file, as I thought I could potentially replace a `%` character with `%%` in order to escape it. However I cannot get it to work.

The syntax is -

```
set string=This is my string to work with.
set string=%string:work=play%
echo %string%
```

Where the output would then be `This is my string to play with.`.

---

**Questions**

1. **Is it possible to escape `%`** characters using the find and replace syntax
    in a variable? (If not, is there another way?)
2. **Is it advisable to do so?** (Could using these escape characters cause any issue in the second batch file which (as mentioned above) we would have no control over?)
3. **Is there another way to handle this issue**, if the above is not possible?

Comment: The file could be processed with `jrepl.bat` by dbenham if the task is suitable for manipulation.  jrepl uses jscript and can handle `poison characters`.

Comment: @foxidrive Do you know how this would affect use of variable values directly in the first script? Variables will likely both be used in the first script (we have control) and also passed to a second (not in our control)

Comment: By "passing to a second file", you mean calling it using `call`?

Comment: @aschipfl Yes, using CALL.

Comment: Your script is not available to see so any answers are guesses but percent characters cannot be handled reliably with plain batch code.

Comment: Okay... the problem is caused by `call` and the fact that it introduces a second `%` parsing phase; so what about passing the variable *names* by `call` rather than the values? I mean, like: `call batch.bat STRING` (instead of `call batch.bat "%STRING%"`), then using `set "ARG=%~1"` and `call set "ARG=%%ARG%%"` (instead of `set "ARG=%~1"`), or, with [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled, `set "ARG=!%~1!"`? this would hide the string from the said second parsing phase...

Comment: using `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` and `set "var=!var:%%=%%%%!"` doesn't work for you when `call otherbatch.bat "%var%"` ?

Comment: @Eilidh The second script isn't under your control, but do you know if it uses (or at least works) with delayed expansion? Do you have to consider only percent signs or also other _poison_ characters like `"<>&^!` ? How do you call your second.bat? With `cmd /c second.bat "%PERCENTVARIABLE%"`, `CALL second.bat "%PERCENTVARIABLE%"` or with `start` ?

Answer (score 2):

There are no simple rules that can be applied in all situations.

There are a few issues that make working with string literals in parameters difficult:

1. Poison characters like `&`, `|`, etc. must be escaped or quoted. Escaping is difficult because it can be confusing as to how many times to escape. So the recommendation is to usually quote the string.
2. Token delimiters like `<space>`, `<tab>`, `=`, `;` and `,` cannot be included in a parameter value unless it is quoted.
3. A CALL to a script will double any quoted `%` characters, and there is ***no way to prevent this***. Executing a script without CALL will not double the `%` characters. But if a script calls another script and expects control to be returned, then CALL must be used.

So we have a catch-22: On the one hand, we want to quote parameters to protect against poison characters and spaces (token delimiters). But to protect percents we don't want to quote.

The only reliable method to reliably pass string literals without concern of value corruption is to pass them by reference via environment variables.

1. The value to be passed should be stored in an environment value. Quotes and/or escapes and/or percent doubling is used to get the necessary characters in the value, but it is very manageable.
2. The name of the variable is passed in as a parameter.
3. The script accesses the value via delayed expansion. For example, if the first parameter is the name of a variable containing the value, then it is accessed as `!%1!`. Delayed expansion must be enabled before that syntax can be used - simply issue `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`.

The beauty of delayed expansion is you never have to worry about corruption of poison characters, spaces, or percents when the variable is expanded.

Here is an example that shows how the following string literal can be passed to a subroutine
`"<%|,;^> This & that!" & the other thing! <%|,;^>`

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "parm1="^<%%^|,;^^^^^> This ^& that^^!" & the other thing^! <%%|,;^^^>"
echo The value before CALL is !parm1!
call :test parm1
exit /b

:test
echo The value after  CALL is !%1!
```

-- OUTPUT --

```
The value before CALL is "<%|,;^> This & that!" & the other thing! <%|,;^>
The value after  CALL is "<%|,;^> This & that!" & the other thing! <%|,;^>
```

But you state that you have no control over the 2nd called script. So the above elegant solution won't work for you.

If you were to show the code of the 2nd script, and show exactly what value you were trying to pass, then I *might* be able to give a solution that would work in that isolated situation. But there are some values that simply cannot be passed unless delayed expansion is used with variable names. (Actually, another option is to put the value in a file and read the value from the file, but that also requires change to your 2nd script)

Answer (score 1):

may be...?

*input.txt*

```
I%LOVE%PERCENT%CHARACTERS%
```

*batch1.bat*

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set/P var=<input.txt
echo(In batch 1 var content: %var%

set "var=!var:%%=%%%%!"
call batch2.bat "%var%"
endlocal
exit/B
```

*batch2.bat*

```
@echo off
set "var=%~1"
echo(In batch 2 var content: %var%
exit/B
```

Comment: This works for `%` but it fails for `^` as they will be doubled. Arguments by value should be avoided with `CALL`, there are to many problems